# How can I make QSSTV recognise my sound device

Tags: sound, qt, internet-radio

After reading [this article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Images-On-An-Audio-Cassette/) from Instructables I wanted to try it out in Ubuntu. Luckily [QSSTV](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/) is available but I'm having problems getting it to work properly.

When pressing the green light (to receive data) I get this error:

[image: QSSTV Receive dialog: Cannot open sounddevice]

After going to **Options > Configure > Interfaces** I discovered that it's attempting to use `/dev/dsp` which doesn't appear to exist.

[image: QSSTV Configuration dialog: Audio Device setting shows /dev/dsp]

In my `/dev` folder there are no files that reference sound devices and I've tried all of the devices in `/dev/snd` but unfortunately none of them work.

Is there a specific audio device that I should be linking to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In January 2012 QSSTV received an update (including an updated interface) that fixed the sound problem. It can be downloaded [from here](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/)

[image]

Comment: The latest QSSTV version 7.1 (pictured above) is available for install in Ubuntu 12.10.  It is also available for previous Ubuntu releases, via the "Ubuntu Hams Updates" PPA:  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-hams-updates/+archive/ppa